# javascript function to execute AFTER browser back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, onunload

Is there a way to trigger an event AFTER the browser back button is clicked? The event will happen AFTER the previous page has been loaded and NOT BEFORE the user exits the current page. From my understanding, onunload event happens before the user leaves the page.

Comment: Imagine a page would be able to execute Javascript AFTER it has redirected you to your Facebook page, or maybe your online banking login? Page requests are seperated from each other, and that for a good reason. What are you trying to build?

Comment: I have a script that resizes the height of an iframe. When clicking on the next button, it will resize the iframe (it will become larger). When the user click on the browser back button, the iframe will retain the large size. What I'd like to do is for the browser to perform the resize function again. I don't have a problem with chrome. Only on IE and Firefox since I read that they are saving the previous state of the page (bfcache)

Comment: I'd guess that you problem is **not** that it doesn't resize, but that it doesn't resize down, if the Iframe could be smaller than it is. A simple solution could be to set the iframe-height to 0 before computing the space its content needs.

Comment: All page has a resize function. When the user clicks browser back, it doesn't perform the onload resize function. Instead of having the actual size, the size of it is the same as the previous page it came from, meaning, all onload events does not perform when the browser back is clicked